# QEMU package not available for RHEL 64 bit

Tags: linux, rhel, qemu

I am installing QEMU in RHEL. In 32 bit OS (i686 architecture), if I run the command, **yum install qemu**, the installation of QEMU takes place. However, in 64 bit architecture (x86_64), if I run the same command, I am getting the error as "**QEMU package not available**". Is the yum installation dependent on the architecture of the OS version?

EDIT:

This is the output of yum list |grep qemu

qemu.i386                             2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-common.i386                      2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-img.i386                         2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-arm.i386                  2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-cris.i386                 2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-m68k.i386                 2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-mips.i386                 2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-ppc.i386                  2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-sh4.i386                  2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-sparc.i386                2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-system-x86.i386                  2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed
qemu-user.i386                        2:0.10.5-1.el5.2        installed

Comment: On my RHEL 6 systems, I can install qemu-kvm and get the userspace QEMU tools. I don't see any `qemu` packages available for either 32 or 64 bit. Where is your `qemu` package coming from in 32-bit land?

Comment: I have a system with i686 architecture. If I run "yum install qemu" I am getting the qemu for i386 architecture. I am confused on why this is happening in i686 architecture but not on x86_64 systems?

Comment: What is the output of `yum list | grep qemu` on your i686 box?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of the command.

Comment: These are RHEL 5 packages, which don't come from Red Hat repositories. Where did you get these packages? (`yum install` doesn't count - what repository did they come from?)

Comment: I ran the command rpm -qi qemu..I see the packager name as Fedora Project.

Comment: Alright, I might have made mistake in the last comment. Sorry about that. This is the package from where I received the QEMU (**qemu-0.10.5-1.el5.2**). I used the command `rpm -qa QEMU`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 64 bit system does not have the appropriate external repository defined for the 64-bit QEMU packages. You will need to find a repository with these packages available and install the appropriate `.repo` file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` before you can `yum install` the QEMU packages. A quick Google search shows that RepoForge has 64-bit QEMU packages available, so that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! That makes real sense. I found that the repo file is missing in the 64 bit machine. Will update the repo file first and then do the yum install.